Which wire to ground to electrical box when pigtailing with wagos?

I have an electrical outlet that was pigtailed and not grounded to the box. Does it matter which ground wire I use to wrap around the screw in the back of the box? Should it be the ground wire coming from the outlet / green screw ?

The box ground wire should be the ground wire that comes from the power source (i.e. the ground wire that comes from the breaker panel, not one that runs on to the next outlet.) If you use a different wire then if the receptacle were to be removed/replaced then you might not have proper grounding any more. With the power source ground wire going to the box it would require deliberate effort to unground the box.

UK is the other way round.  It optional if the box si grounded.

The rule is that the box must remain grounded even if the device is removed.
Feel free to attach othe incoming and outgoing cable grounds to the box only, and then get ground to the receptacle any of these ways.

The receptacle is labeled "Self-Grounding" which will be the case for most GFCIs and better ($3+) receptacles. This is a wiper which assures good contact with the mounting screws.
Switches can do this even if not marked Self-Grounding.
The receptacle does not float above the box on the drywall ears, and actually has hard clean flush metal contact between box flange and receptacle yoke.


All the ground wires should be tied together, so it really doesn't matter which is attached to ground the box.
If the box is grounded there is not a need for a ground wire to the outlet. It will be grounded by the attachment screws. So for your installation you can disconnect the ground wire at the outlet and attach to the ground screw in the back of the box.

Looking close at the outlet it does not appear to have that taught-wire "spring" on one end of the yoke which holds firmly on the screw, which I think is the thing that enables grounding through the screws and yoke. Might this outlet not be the ground by screw type? Then separate ground wires to the outlet and the box might be needed, requiring a four-gang Wago or an extended ground wire wrapped around the box ground screw then to the outlet?

Typically switches are OK without an explicit spring contact on one screw, and receptacles are NOT (has to do with likely ground fault current for the different types of devices.) A 3-port with the incoming ground to the box screw, then on to the Wago (other Wago ports to recptacle and next outlet) would work.
